# CSS box-shadow fall behind flash player in firefox

Tags: html, css

I want to create a dropdown menu with css box-shadow around it and I have a few content using flash, the problem's when dropdown show up and have flash behind it, box-shadow is not show.
actually the box-shadow fall behind flash player

I simplfy the structure 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/QEjlt.jpg]

I'm using Firefox 17.0.1 , chrome 23.0.1271.97 and flash player 11.5.502.135

Style

```
.test { position:absolute; z-index: 100; left:50%; top:30px; border:3px solid blue;width:200px; height:200px; background:gray; box-shadow:50px 50px 130px #000}
#flash{ position:absolute; left:50%; z-index:-100}
```

HTML Structure

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div id="flash">    
<object width="100%" height="400" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
<param value="28bc2_2.swf" name="SRC">
<embed width="100%" height="400" src="28bc2_2.swf">
</object>
</div>
```

Anybody know what happens and the solution, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Try addding: -moz-box-shadow:50px 50px 130px #000000;

Comment: thanks dude for your response. but it seems not work. when I tried not even single shadow show.

Comment: oh ya I have thought maybe firefox not support any -moz-box-shadow anymore. because Firefox 17.0.1 alredy using css3 w3c standard box-shadow

Answer (score 1):

To get the box-shadow crossbrowser you need the following code:

```
box-shadow: 50px 50px 130px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 50px 50px 130px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 50px 50px 130px #000;
```

Also try adding `wmode` parameter to embed flash:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div id="flash">    
<object width="100%" height="400" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
<param value="28bc2_2.swf" name="SRC">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<embed width="100%" height="400" wmode="transparent" src="28bc2_2.swf">
</object>
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks dude, the problem is wmode paramater. After I put the parameter, box-shadow now work perfectly. Oh ya for info -moz-box-shadow seems not work for this FF version (17.0.1)

Comment: @Finn How nice! I only ask, please, tell you what my answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: yes fred, your answer is correct. adding wmode parameter will fix the problem :)

Comment: @Finn Please, read section "How to ask" in FAQ: [http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using cross-browser css... (-moz- and -webkit- like others have mentioned)

Try setting the z-index value of `.test` higher than the z-index value of `#flash`. Also, try placing #flash within the div with `.test` class.

Right now it seems that you set the z-index of your flash div to -100, and the z-index of your test (is this your menu?) to 100... so naturally your flash content would be behind `.test`.

Comment: In addition to using cross-browser css... (-moz- and -webkit- like others have mentioned)
----> it seems -moz not work on this version Firefox 17.0.1, dont know why

Comment: Try setting the z-index value of .test higher than the z-index value of #flash. Also...
----> sorry it not possible, the html structure suppose to be like that. because .test is dropdown menu and #flash is content page.

Right now it seems that you set the z-index of your flash div to -100, and the z-index of your...
---> ya, flash content is right behind .test with this z-index. but still the shadow fall behind flash content.  Oh ya, I tried using small z-index like 50 (not minus), stil not work :(